# what to include in the C2DM collapse_key filed

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I'm implementing C2DM on my android push application, this is what google said about collapse_key:

"*An arbitrary string that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the last message sent by the application server. Required.*"

I was wondering what if i want to get all the push sent during the device offline, what should i have in the collapse_key and how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

I think you should then make a new/different collaps-key for every message. You could just have an integer that keeps getting bigger over time or you could just use the system time...

Answer (score 2):

While CD2M was deprecreated in favor for GCM, **take into account** that at least GCM allows to have only 4 collapse keys

> GCM allows a maximum of 4 different collapse keys to be used by the
>   GCM server at any given time. In other words, the GCM server can
>   simultaneously store 4 different send-to-sync messages, each with a
>   different collapse key. If you exceed this number GCM will only keep 4
>   collapse keys, with no guarantees about which ones they will be.